# Ansible shell command doesn't seem to have access to the user's shell environment

Tags: ansible

Im trying to use a ruby installed via RBENV.  I have confirmed that RBENV works as desired and produces the correct ruby version which can be called via the terminal

`ruby -v` returns: `ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-linux]` which is the desired version

`bundler -v` returns: `Bundler version 2.3.10` which is also the desired version.

However the following tasks in my playbook fail

```
- block:

  - name: 'set ruby version'
    shell: echo eval "$(rbenv init -)" >> ~/.zshrc

  - name: 'set global ruby verison'
    shell: 'rbenv global {{ ruby_version }}'

  - name: 'restart shell'
    shell: $shell

  - name: 'Bundle install'
    shell:
      chdir: "{{ app_path }}"
      cmd: bundle install

  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ deploy_user}}'
```

I get the following output when trying to execute these tasks in my playbook

```
fatal: [45.77.186.234]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "bundle install", "delta": "0:00:00.001967", "end": "2022-03-25 00:33:48.231712", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2022-03-25 00:33:48.229745", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

On the [docs page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) for ansible.builtin.shell the 3rd bullet point under synopsis indicates that the shell command is executed using the user's shell environment.  I can't see anywhere that I'm supposed to define which shell specifically, I wonder if my use of ZSH is where the problem is?

At this point I've tried everything I can think of, and now Im asking for help.  How do I run a shell command against the user's shell environment?

Comment: May be , `source .zshrc` is needed to take effect the changes in zshrc. Not tested, only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to execute chained zsh commands to get this to work for me.

```
- name: Install fastlane gem
  command: zsh -lc "source ~/.zshrc && gem install fastlane"
```

I didn't have to do this before I updated my MacOS system to 12.3.1, for what it's worth. It seems like some default behavior changed for shell execution.